# gitlist cannot get anything beyond repository list

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to setup gitlist on CentOS Linux (with gitolite in case that matters -- I have relaxed the permissions on the repo directories managed by gitolite).

I extracted the version 0.3 tarball from today from gitlist.org.

My config.ini looks like this:

```
client = '/usr/bin/git' ; Your git executable path
repositories = '/home/gitolite/repositories/' ; Path to your repositories

[app]
debug = true    
; I don't know if baseurl is still needed..seems like my results are the same either way
baseurl = 'http://sub.example.com.com/gitlist' ; Base URL of the application
```

virtual host directive in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName sub.example.com
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /var/www/html/gitlist/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NC]

  AuthName "Git List"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /var/www/.gitlistpwds
  Require valid-user

</IfModule>
<Files config.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

With this setup, going to http://sub.example.com/gitlist results in the browser error message saying that /index.php does not exist (i.e. it's trying to go to /var/www/html/index.php )

In this case if I go to http://sub.example.com/gitlist/index.php, the repository list (apparently) properly appears.  When I click on one of the repos, something goes wrong when it tries to execute, git. I get:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 RuntimeException: Unknown option: -c
(std git usage message omitted)
```

If I remove the rewrite rule from .htaccess, I am able to access the index page by either specifying index.php or not.  But in that case when I click on a repo, it tries to find the repo underneath the gitlist directory:

```
The requested URL /gitlist/testing.git/ was not found on this server.
```

Can someone please help sort out this mess?

Comment: Why the rewrite? Put your gitlist webapp wherever you want, declare an alias and a Directory, and it should be enough (as in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L41-L93)

Comment: The rewrite is part of the app (it ships with an .htaccess that contains it).  I don't know why it is there.  I did try it without, as I indicated, and I still had problems.  Are you saying that if I move it outside my web directory the problem will go away?

Comment: I am just pointing out other technique to reference a webapp without having to use rewrite. I will have to test gitlist and see if it works that way too.

Comment: That would be awesome thanks.

Comment: I finally had to use rewrite. I just didn't use an `.htaccess` file. The end result works, but isn't complete (see the link to Issue 250 at the end of my answer), and I still have to plug in somehow gitolite, if I want any user access right management.

Comment: I had a similar issue which was related to file access rights, see https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/345

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to test gitlist.

I removed the `.htaccess`, and kept the following config in httpd.conf:

```
# GitList on 28473
<IfModule !php5_module>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>
Listen 28473
<VirtualHost aserver.prod.fr.company:28473>
    ServerName aserver.prod.fr.company
    ServerAlias aserver
    SSLCertificateFile "/home/vonc/apache/crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vonc/apache/key"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "/home/vonc/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
    DocumentRoot /home/vonc/gitlist/github
    Alias /gitlist /home/vonc/gitlist/github
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".php$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".phps$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /home/vonc/gitlist/github>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews

        DirectoryIndex index.php
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteBase /home/vonc/gitlist/github/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gitlist/index.php/$1 [L,NC]

    </Directory>

    # RewriteLog "/home/vonc/gitlist/logs/apache_gitlist_rewrite_log"
    # RewriteLogLevel 3
    CustomLog "/home/vonc/gitlist/logs/apache_gitlist_ssl_request_log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    ErrorLog "/home/vonc/gitlist/logs/apache_gitlist_error_log"
    TransferLog "/home/vonc/gitlist/logs/apache_gitlist_access_log"
    LogLevel info
</VirtualHost>
```

(From [my own commit](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/commit/d689ab01104a3f85fbbc86171a29570a962a58cb), and [this setup](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/tree/gitlist/gitlist))

Note that:

- this is for running gitlist in its own subdirectory: `https://myServer/gitlist` (not just `https://myserver`)
- It won't display any files under a subdirectory within a git repo: see [Issue 250](https://github.com/klaussilveira/gitlist/issues/250), the patch is pending

Comment: VonC thanks for your efforts.  My main problem was actually centered around the unknown option error that I mentioned, which I fixed by updating my git executable.  I'm still having an error when I try to access my repo, but that error is 'Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git' which doesn't seem related to my original question/problem.